# FragmentPagerAdapter - Incompatible Types

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

Am attempting this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id46JCY76f0. Have followed it word for word, but have reached 16:00 into the video and this particular code is throwing me a Incompatible Type error:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;


public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int pageCount=3;
Bundle info;

public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    info= new Bundle();


    switch (pos){
        case 0;
            Asia asia = new Asia();
            info.putInt("currentPager", pos++);
            asia.setArguments(info);
            return asia;

        case 1;
            Africa africa = new Africa();
            info.putInt("currentPager", pos++);
            africa.setArguments(info);
            return africa;
        case 2;
            Europe eu = new Europe();
            info.putInt("currentPager", pos++);
            eu.setArguments(info);
            return eu;
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

}

Error:

Required android.support.v4.app.Fragment
Found    com.example.petakirikiri.swipetabs.Asia

```
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class Asia extends ListFragment{

String[] countries = {"India", "Pakistan", "Malaysia", "Bangladesh", "Singapore"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countries);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you extending Asia with Fragment? 
Also, Fragment in this case must match - i.e there are two types:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

and

```
android.app.Fragment;
```

If they aren't the same you'll get a type mismatch error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, I just updated the code, is it what you mentioned? I believe the Asia class is extending ListFragment, it seems to work for the guy in the tutorial video, not sure why it's not working for me, as I feel like I've written everything line for line. Perhaps its due to my imports?

Comment: Thank you, you're feedback helped me a lot and it's now working. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: ListFragment also has two variations but you can tell which one you're using with your import statements. Glad I could help :)